# Get the SecretKey value generated by KeyGenerator and send it to the server

Tags: android, encryption, android-keystore

Need to implement end-to-end encryption on an app. All data sent and received is going to be encrypted. Need to send symmetric secret key generated on app and stored in the Android Keystore to the server after encrypting it with the public key which I get from the server. Problem : I am unable to get the string/bytes value of the SecretKey which I want to encrypt.

I have a helper class which does the work of generating the SecretKey and stores and retrieves it when required from the keystore. Data gets correctly encrypted and decrypted, however due to the requirement of end-end encryption(all data in transit must also be encrypted), I need to send the secretkey to the server, but I cannot get access to it. 
There are three getter methods in the SecretKey class. 
getAlgortithm - This returns "AES" as expected
getEncoded - This returns null
getFormat - This also returns null

```
public class EncryptionKeyGenerator {
public static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
public static final String KEY_ALIAS = "KEY_ALIAS";
private static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_NAME = "KEY_STORE";
private static final String KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "KEY_STORE_PASSWORD";

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
static SecurityKey generateSecretKey(KeyStore keyStore) {
    try {
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator =
                    KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
            keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT).setBlockModes(
                    KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                    .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                    .build());
            return new SecurityKey(keyGenerator.generateKey());
        }
    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
    }
    try {
        final KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry entry =
                (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
        return new SecurityKey(entry.getSecretKey());
    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
        CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
    }
    return null;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    static SecurityKey generateKeyPairPreM(Context context, KeyStore keyStore)    {
    try {
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
            Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
            //1 Year validity
            end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

            KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context).setAlias(KEY_ALIAS)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + KEY_ALIAS))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
                    .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                    .build();

            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
            kpg.initialize(spec);
            kpg.generateKeyPair();
        }
    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
    }

    try {
        final KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry =
                (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
        return new SecurityKey(
                new KeyPair(entry.getCertificate().getPublicKey(), entry.getPrivateKey()));
    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
        CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
    }
    return null;
}

static SecurityKey generateSecretKeyPre18(Context context) {

    try {
        KeyStore androidCAStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        char[] password = KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray();

        boolean isKeyStoreLoaded = loadKeyStore(context, androidCAStore, password);
        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);
        if (!isKeyStoreLoaded || !androidCAStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
            //Create and save new secret key
            saveMyKeystore(context, androidCAStore, password, protParam);
        }

        // Fetch Secret Key
        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry pkEntry =
                (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) androidCAStore.getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, protParam);

        CommonMethods.printLog("e", "Secret Key Fetched :" + new String(pkEntry.getSecretKey().getEncoded(), "UTF-8"), EncryptionKeyGenerator.class.getSimpleName());
        return new SecurityKey(pkEntry.getSecretKey());
    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
        CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean loadKeyStore(Context context, KeyStore androidCAStore, char[] password) {
    java.io.FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(KEY_STORE_FILE_NAME);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
        return false;
    }
    try {
        androidCAStore.load(fis, password);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
        CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
    }
    return false;
}

private static void saveMyKeystore(Context context, KeyStore androidCAStore, char[] password,
                                   KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException {

    javax.crypto.SecretKey mySecretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();

    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(mySecretKey);
    androidCAStore.load(null);
    androidCAStore.setEntry(KEY_ALIAS, skEntry, protParam);
    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(KEY_STORE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        androidCAStore.store(fos, password);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    }
    CommonMethods.printLog("e", "Secret Key Saved : " + new String(mySecretKey.getEncoded(), "UTF-8"), EncryptionKeyGenerator.class.getSimpleName());
}
```

}

```
class SecurityKey {
private static final String RSA_MODE = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
private static final String AES_MODE_FOR_POST_API_23 = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
private static final String AES_MODE_FOR_PRE_API_18 = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

private SecretKey secretKey;
private KeyPair keyPair;

SecurityKey(SecretKey secretKey) {
this.secretKey = secretKey;
}

SecurityKey(KeyPair keyPair) {
this.keyPair = keyPair;
 }

String encrypt(String token) {
if (token == null) return null;

try {
  Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);

  byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(token.getBytes());
  return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
  CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
}
//Unable to encrypt Token
return null;
  }

String decrypt(String encryptedToken) {
if (encryptedToken == null) return null;

try {
  Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);

  byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(encryptedToken, Base64.DEFAULT);
  byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
  return new String(original);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
  CommonMethods.printStackTrace(e);
}
//Unable to decrypt encrypted Token
return null;
}

private Cipher getCipher(int mode) throws GeneralSecurityException {
Cipher cipher;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE_FOR_POST_API_23);
  cipher.init(mode, secretKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128,   AES_MODE_FOR_POST_API_23.getBytes(), 0, 12));
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_MODE);
  cipher.init(mode, mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE ? keyPair.getPublic() :   keyPair.getPrivate());
} else {
  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE_FOR_PRE_API_18);
  cipher.init(mode, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
}
return cipher;
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent, see the signal protocol. It is opensource.

Comment: Rather than reinventing the protocol, better to use existing protocols like, HTTPS, SFTP etc.

Comment: i have read this tutorial: https://proandroiddev.com/secure-data-in-android-encryption-in-android-part-1-e5fd150e316f
may be helpful for your case :)